# Generating UUID for API tokens in Python

Tags: python, secret-key

I'm currently generating UUIDs in Python as follows:

```
import uuid
import secrets

uuid.UUID(bytes=secrets.token_bytes(16))
```

Is this safe to be used as an API token or access token?

Comment: A UUID as a token has the limitation of a 128 bits space. If you can live with that your code is fine. Of cause a longer key will always be more secure. Especially because token are easier to guess the more valid there are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two reasons that your current approach is, arguably, a safe and sound one:

- the probability of generating a duplicate id with 128 bits of entropy is [effectively nil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions). (This is the standard UUID size, which you are using.)
- `secrets` is designed specifically with the purpose of generating cryptographically strong random numbers; `token_bytes()` is really just a call to `os.urandom()`, which in turn returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source.*

A suggestion - `uuid.uui4()` does basically this same exact thing without the overhead of calling intermediary functions:

```
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/uuid.py
def uuid4():
    """Generate a random UUID."""
    return UUID(bytes=os.urandom(16), version=4)
```

One other suggestion regardless - you can use `.hex` of the resulting UUID object to get a nice non-hyphenated string.

```
>>> uuid.uuid4().hex
'22c482ef3cd84c26bb49c0287828428f'
```

<sub>*On Unix, that's `/dev/urandom`, which collects info from sources like device drivers.  I.e. garbled info that is particular to the generating machine but sufficiently random and not identifiable of the host computer itself.</sub>